# Alternative to Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data

Tags: .net, .net-framework-version

Does anyone know an alternative to  Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data
 which has since been deprecated and now when I bring it in to VS2010 for the 1st time it wont even compile. Even if i keep the application an ASP.NET 2.0 Framework app, it still throws errors.

This is an old legacy application that I just inherited and I dont even quite know what the library is used for but its causing my app to critically fail.

Comment: can you list few of the features you are looking for contained in that package?

Comment: I just edited the question. I dont even know what its used for.

Comment: why does not compile? don't you have the dll referenced locally?

Comment: Here is Microsoft's official explanation of what it does: The Database class leverages the provider factory model from ADO.NET. A database instance holds a reference to a concrete DbProviderFactory object to which it forwards the creation of ADO.NET objects.

Comment: @david, its not a dll. Its a system reference.

Comment: no, it is not a default system namespace, that's why it is failing, you should download the correct version of the MS EnterpriseLibrary package containing that assembly and reference it from Visual Studio, deprecated or Obsolete ok but if you still have it and reference it, it should still work. Also look at this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413514/what-is-microsoft-practices-enterpriselibrary-data

Comment: @DavidePiras can you put your last answer in as an answer instead of a comment so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data` is not a default system namespace, that's why it is failing, you should download the correct version of the MS EnterpriseLibrary package containing that assembly and reference it from Visual Studio, deprecated or Obsolete ok but if you still have it and reference it, it should still work.

Also look at this one:

[what is Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14413514/what-is-microsoft-practices-enterpriselibrary-data)

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for an [object relational mapper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) and the list of options for .NET is pretty long

- My orm of choice is [ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite)
- [Entity Framework,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) is Microsoft's official entry
- [Dapper](https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net) is a lightweight orm, which, I believe, was created for StackOverflow
- [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/) is a port of Java's Hibernate and is the grandaddy of code first ORMs
- [Massive](https://github.com/robconery/massive) is another lightweight orm developed by Rob Conery of subsonic fame

There are a ton more, these are the first ones that came to mind